# Failed to load OpenCL runtime - OpenCV3 Python

Tags: python, opencv, opencl, py2exe

I have a program that processes videos using foreground detection in OpenCV 2.4.9/python/on windows and packaged for a windows executable using py2exe. I recently updated opencv to opencv3 and repackaged my program. When i run on my computer (with opencv3 installed locally) everything goes fine.

However, when a user goes and downloads the program and runs it on another computer, they get the warning

```
Failed to load OpenCL runtime
```

This just seems to be just a warning, and i can detect no performance issues.

I have a couple options. I can just suppress this specific warning in a try statement, or i can somehow turn off the OpenCL on my computer for packaging the program. Suggestions on either strategy would be appreciated. Anything i am overlooking? To my understanding the OpenCL library is for acceleration using GPU.

Thanks,

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: edited, pasted by accident. different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution will be compiling the OpenCV libs without OpenCL and then link them to your application

Comment: Would i have to compile from source, edited to mention this is on Windows. I've gone back and there isn't anything in the windows binary giving this option. Thanks.

Comment: you have to download OpenCV from github, then compile with ENABLE_OPENCL=OFF (using CMake) and use the built libs against your application

Comment: WITH_OPENCL=OFF  (not enable_opencl)

Comment: I've tried the flag, and building with the new library generated from cmake. Still getting the error. On some computers it just gives the warning flag and no consequences and on computers it gives a fatal error: opencl device not found check configuration.

Comment: Is the foreground extraction algorithm using any on GPU/OpenCL approach? If so, it won't work.
On other side, if the libraries are compiled with WITH_OPENCL=OFF, then you should not get this error. Try to do a clean build and be sure you are linking the right libraries with your project.

Comment: Hello, my question is similar to this, but my need is a little bit different. May be you know the answer to my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342179/opencv-failed-to-load-opencl-runtime) ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had encounter the same problem, here's my solution:

1. go to the Intel [website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl) and download the OpenCL library, then unzip it
2. run the `install.sh` file

If your install fails because of `update-alternatives` errors, maybe it's because you are using Ubuntu/Debian distro and the Intel install package has a wrong setting with it.

To solve this, [xfanzone](http://xfanzone.me) did a very good job on this. Take a look [here](http://xfanzone.me/fixing-opencl-deb.html).

1. download the patch zip file and patch your OpenCL package
2. install it again, now it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

If you just don't need to use OpenCL, you can set the environment var as below:

```
export OPENCV_OPENCL_RUNTIME=999
```

Sometimes, if you want to turn on the opencl:

```
export OPENCV_OPENCL_RUNTIME=
```