# OpenCV: Failed to load OpenCL runtime

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, opencl, opencv3.0

I am running a program in which I got the error on the title of my question. I have found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723059/failed-to-load-opencl-runtime-opencv3-python) that suggests to  download OpenCV from github, then compile with `ENABLE_OPENCL=OFF` (using CMake) and use the built libs against the  application.

Or may be is there a way to set this flag in the program itself without modifying anything in OpenCV ?

I wonder if it is possible to do that without having to remove and install again OpenCV-3.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by running:

`sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-opencl-dev`